# 3 downvotes -> revamping the answer, next steps?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I've revamped my answer that was downvoted thrice. Can I somehow get in touch with folks who downvoted it so they can look at it again? I know one, so I gave him a shout in comments.

Or is it better to actually delete and repost?

[Checkout bitbucket pull requests locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967034/checkout-bitbucket-pull-requests-locally/29655984#29655984)

Comment: There's nothing you can do unless they've commented and you can comment back saying you've attempted to improve your answer.  Just let it be.  If people find it helpful, they will upvote.

Comment: On your comment to the answer: downvotes are anonymous, and there is no privilege for de-anonymising them, so the commenter there is just as unaware of the identity of the other downvoters as you and me.

Comment: The old answer looks like it has been completely replaced. You could rollback (and delete if it was no good), then post it as a new answer.

Comment: I concur with @AlexanderO'Mara. When you completely replace an answer with a better answer, and need a fresh start, deleting and reposting is problably the best option when the original has several downvotes

Comment: I concur too with @AlexanderO'Mara

Comment: Why on earth is this question downvoted? It's a valid and on-topic question, does not appear to be a duplicate (or, at least, nobody has yet voted to close it as such), and it's not making a proposal that one might reasonably downvote due to simple disagreement.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen if my 40 minutes reading on downvotes here and there gave me good info (don't know how can I validate that) that probably means somebody on meta dislikes my question and expresses disagreement. To what part, don't know, but since my new, revamped answer got further downvotes despite working and since this question got much more downvotes, I think it's good to assume that deletion of original answer is what's required. As for new answer, I'm not sure if I should post it or not, but that's another matter. Thanks to everybody for comments and guidance (not a sarcasm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the bad answer. If you have different solution - create a new answer, if existing answer should be fixed - move on or come up with fixes and un-delete.

Similarly to questions, recovery of downvotes is unlikely - there could be rare cases when a post gets large number of views and edited version of the answer is brilliant, but you may as well go and win [Powerball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerball) if you are so lucky. There is no way to notify people who downvoted that post. Sometimes voters will comment - you'll be able to individually address those people in hope they see updated post.

If your answer is really bad (usually 2 or more downvotes) it is better to delete the answer (possibly getting the [Peer Pressure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge) and start over. 
Note that if you just fixing existing answer delete-and-start-over is wrong approach - you should edit existing answer instead. So if reputation is of top concern for you and you don't have *new* solution - keep the answer deleted and move on to other questions.

Before posting a new answer or restoring existing one, make sure to understand why the original one was downvoted and make sure all problems are addressed with new solution. Check if the question is actually on-topic and not duplicate. Make sure you read the question similarly to other readers - you may be answering a totally different question.

If the wrong approach is taken in the original answer, and it is something others may try - consider adding a section at the end with a text like "the following solutions are wrong because ..."

---

On this particular answer: I don't know anything about bitbucket - so I can't really comment on that post, but if you want to prove that your answer is correct it is better to *explain* why it should work. This is especially important in case when there is a reasonable ["this can't work" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40948201/477420). Also you probably should improve the question while you are at it.

Comment: Re-posting negatively scored post just to remove downvotes is abusive behavior, and worth flagging for moderation attention whenever you see it.  It is *not* acceptable behavior.

Comment: @Servy Thanks!.I read question as "replacing bad answer with different one" - I'll update post to clarify that.

Comment: Thanks to you and @AlexanderO'Mara. Will do that.